# Turtle Float Error while using dot() vs stamp()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-3.9

While using this function, I don't get the error -

```
    # Dot poulator
    def dotPlot( x, y, z):
        dots = 0
        goto((-z+pad),(z-pad))
        while x > 0:
            a = randrange((-z+pad),(z-pad), 1)
            b = randrange((-z+pad),(z-pad), 1)
            penup()
            goto(a,b)
            pendown()
            stamp()
            x -= 1
```

but when I change the function to make a dot instead of a stamp, I get a float error.

```
    # Dot poulator
    def dotPlot( x, y, z):
        dots = 0
        goto((-z+pad),(z-pad))
        while x > 0:
            a = randrange((-z+pad),(z-pad), 1)
            b = randrange((-z+pad),(z-pad), 1)
            penup()
            goto(a,b)
            pendown()
            dot()
            x -= 1
```

Error details:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".py", line 136, in <module>
        dotPlot(res, min, max)
      File ".py", line 115, in dotPlot
        dot()
    TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: The dot function requires a color argument, unlike stamp which takes no arguments.

Comment: @Fred, both arguments to `dot()` (diameter and color) are optional.  That's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped with sufficient code, a call to your `dotPlot()` of the form:

```
dotPlot(100, None, 20)
```

works fine for me.  My guess is you have a variable called `dot` whose name is conflicting with the turtle function `dot()`.  If so, kick yourself for using a wildcard import.